# How would I best implement a system that prevents the calling of one method, if said method has already been applied?

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean

One part of what I'm working on requires me to prompt the user to choose if they want a .txt file to be organized via the last name alphabetically or vice versa. I've gotten all the code down so my trouble isn't in editing or changing my .txt file but I want to prevent the user from selecting last name if last name has already been applied or vice versa. Basically, like a light switch, where if it's on (organized first name) then the only option is off (organize by last name).

I'm not sure how to best describe this, but if you run the code firstOrLast.equals("last") then run firstOrLast.equals("first") it will do nothing, but you can continue to run "last". I believe my error involves how I assign the boolean when checking what its current value is.

```
   public static boolean isFirst = true;

   public static void sortPatientsByName(String firstOrLast, String fileName) throws IOException {
        if (firstOrLast.equals("last")) {  // CODE FOR LAST NAME, FIRST NAME
            if (isFirst == true) {    // BOOLEAN TO SEE IF OTHER HAS BEEN CALLED
                FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
                String[] words = null;
                ArrayList<String> sortName = new ArrayList<>();
                String line = "";
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    words = line.split(" ");
                    String swapFirst = "";
                    String swapLast = "";
                    String holdBirth = "";
                    String holdStatus = "";
                    swapFirst = words[1];
                    swapLast = words[0];
                    holdBirth = words[2];
                    holdStatus = words[3];
                    line = swapFirst + " " + swapLast + " " + holdBirth + " " + holdStatus;
                    sortName.add(line);
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                Collections.sort(sortName);
                FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(fileName);
                for (int i = 0; i < sortName.size(); i++) {
                    writer.write(sortName.get(i));
                    writer.write("\r\n");
                }
                writer.close();
                //isFirst = false;  // NOT SURE IF ASSIGNING BOOLEAN FALSE SHOULD BE CALLED WITHIN
            }
            isFirst = false;
        }
        if (firstOrLast.equals("first")) {  // CODE FOR FIRST NAME, LAST NAME
            if (isFirst == false) {   // BOOLEAN TO SEE IF OTHER HAS BEEN CALLED
                FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
                ArrayList<String> sortName = new ArrayList<>();
                String line = "";
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sortName.add(line);
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                Collections.sort(sortName);
                FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(fileName);
                for (int i = 0; i < sortName.size(); i++) {
                    writer.write(sortName.get(i));
                    writer.write("\r\n");
                }
                writer.close();
                //isFirst = true;
            }
            isFirst = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that when you start your code the only thing that can run is the "first" part.

You can try to change the boolean type to Boolean and set it to null like :

`static Boolean isFirst = null`

Then in your code you check if boolean is null (for the first time is run) and at then end of the run set it to the corresponding value:

```
static Boolean isFirst = null;

public static void sortPatientsByName() throws IOException {
        if (firstOrLast.equals("last")) {
            if (isFirt == null || isFirst == false) {
               ***
               isFirst = false;
            }
        if (firstOrLast.equals("first")) {
            if (isFirt == null || isFirst == true) {
               ***
               isFirst = true;
            }
        }
```

That way when you'll run it it pass the first time due to null and after it can only pass to the first one it pass through

One cleaner way would be to create a enum for the different possibility